# How to update Python to the latest version on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, python-2.7

I am trying to update my python version but whenever I try:

```
 pip install --upgrade python
```

the output is:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade
your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop
support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already up-to-date: python in /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload (2.7.12)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I do not believe you can. It will break all the software that depends on python2. I would advice to install 18.04.

Comment: You should be able to install python3.x for user environments but don't update the system python. See Rinzwind's comment for why. If there is no python3 in the 16.04 repos you can get it elsewhere but what is your reason for not moving to 18.04?

Comment: Python3 is also automatically installed in 16.04. To use it, just give command "python3 your_program.py"

Comment: This answer on serverfault describes how this may be done:
https://serverfault.com/questions/918335/best-way-to-run-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-which-comes-with-python-3-5

Answer (score 9):

- You *cannot update* python versions within the first two digits (As far, as I am concerned)

That is, although, you **can** update `python3.8` from your current version (let's say `3.8.2`) into the highest available at repository (let's say `3.8.5`) by the standard `sudo apt-get update`, you **cannot** update from `python3.8` to `python3.9`, neither from `python2.7` into `python 3.5`: you **must install** the new version **parallel** to the first one. In that way, both versions `3.8` and `3.9` would be installed in your Ubuntu.

For instance, in your case, if you do as @Rustam says `sudo apt-get install python3.8`, you would not update `python2.7` to `python3.8`, but you would have **both** python versions installed `2.7` and `3.8`.

- Why can we only install parallel versions instead of updating?

The reason was given by @Rinzwind. If we remove another version of python, we could break all software depending on that version, i.e., we may not be able to run it with the new version. The best example is the incompatibility of python2 and python3 software. But I have also experienced problems trying to run `python3.5` software with `python3.8`.

- Now, which of all python versions uses my Ubuntu?

You can see that by means of the "python links". These are links in the `/usr/bin` directory. Just go there and run `ll | grep python`. You will see 3 important links: `python` `python2` and `python3` that tell you the versions that your operative system uses.

For example, in my Ubuntu I have

```
python -> python3
python2 -> python2.7
python3 -> python3.8
```

Which means, if `python` is executed without specifying any version, `python3` will be the chosen version. If `python2` is executed then the chosen version is `2.7`. And finally if `python3` is executed then the chosen version is `3.8`.

Answer (score 5):

PIP is used to install python packages to your python installations. It is not meant for the installation of new python versions. For this you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8
```

This is currently the latest version. You already have python 3.x in Ubuntu. To get its version, run "python3 --version". If you have 3.6.3 for example, you can update it up to 3.6.9, but you can't turn it into 3.7 or 3.8 - this should be a separate installations.
Keeping you python environments separate is quite useful - take a look at this guide: [Installing packages using pip and virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

Comment: Ubutu 16.04 has a python 3.5